# / got corrupted and showing as ext2

Tags: sles

There is a SLES11.4 server that got grub error 15, loading at stage 1.5. Ok, no info on what happened to it.

Ok, I booted the SLES11 DVD in rescue, starts getting exciting :)

With lsblk I can see the filesystems, ok.

/dev/sda1 was the /

/dev/sda2 has LVM, and has LV: var and tmp, those look good. Don't know who puts / on a partition and var/tmp on LVM.

I try to mount / with (in the livecd/rescue session): "mount /dev/sda1 /mnt".

I can see only an empty lost+found dir.. and it is saying it is ext2, strange, no files.

It was an ext3 before.

We got a healthy machine that is the pair of this bad one, let's call the good one: "01".

So far I tried:

- I tried to fsck the /dev/sda1, but it says it is clean, doesn't do anything.
- Tried to check the data what is on the sda1 and sda on this bad vs. the good system, looks like there is data on the bad one too..but why isn't the FS recognized? : [image] sda looks the same.
- Tried to fsck.ext3 too, the same: clean and still no files besides lost+found if I mount sda1

**The big Q**: any chances to get back the old /? Before doing a clean reinstall.

Comment: try specifying an ext3 fsck to see if forcing it to look for the ext3 journal makes a difference.  `fsck.ext3 /dev/sda1`

Comment: thx, tried, but no luck :)