# What to modify if I dd sda1 to another machine?

Tags: linux, sles, cloning

There are 2 servers, they were application level clusters.

One of the servers / got corrupted, see: [/ got corrupted and showing as ext2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451320/got-corrupted-and-showing-as-ext2)

The idea is the next: I would dd the sda1 from the good server to the bad one.

**The Q**: what should I update on the bad machine, after dd'ing the sda1?

My hints so far:

- grep -r HOSTNAME /* and modify it
- vi /etc/sysconfig/network/*
- re-generate /etc/ssh/ssh_host_
- vi /etc/fstab
- vi /etc/hosts
- vi /etc/passwd and /etc/group
- generate new blkid for sda1